# Yii2 pass big array from one view to another controller

Tags: php, yii2, parameter-passing

I have big array, it is result of controller

```
public function actionAaaa()
    {
        //somoethig, effect array
        return $this->render('test', [
        'array' => $array
        ]);
    }
```

For example in view:

```
<pre>
    <?print_r($array);
</pre>
```

Now I want pass this array from view to another action controller.
I don't know how do this.
I'm try:

```
<button type="submit" id="test" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Test</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#test").click(function () {
            var variable = <?=$array?>;
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'controller/action',
                data: variable,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

but when I try use next controller, I don't see anything:

```
public function actionBBBB()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $tablica = $request->post();

        echo 'Tablica POST';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($tablica);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'XXXxxxXXX';
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: The url you are using on your AJAX call is `controller/action`, but your action is named `actionBBBB`. This could be *one* of the reasons why you don't see anything. Instead of `controller/action`, try using `controller/b-b-b-b`. Why is your action named `actionBBBB` in the first place? Try using a more descriptive name like `actionDisplayBigArray` and your `actionAaaa` be named like `actionGenerateBigArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to post the entire array like that. You can however serialize it to do so:

```
var variable = <?serialize($array);?>
```

Then you can `unserialize` it later.

This is just one alternative. Some would say its bad. Probably is. You can also use `SESSION`